# Enum acts strange in TouchEvent

Tags: android, enums, touch, libgdx

I have some trouble with my enum in my touchDown method from InputProcessor. When I try to use it it generates all the possible enums...

```
public class Memoration implements ApplicationListener, InputProcessor {

public static enum Screen {GAME, MENU}
Screen screen;

@Override
public void create() {
   screen = Screen.MENU;
   Gdx.app.log("onCreate", "works");
   Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
}

@Override
public void render() {
   // bla bla bla
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    Gdx.app.log("touch", "down");
    if(screen == null) 
       Gdx.app.log("screen", "null");
    if(screen == Screen.MENU) 
        Gdx.app.log("screen", "menu");
    if(screen == Screen.GAME) 
        Gdx.app.log("screen", "game");
    return false;
}
}
```

The log show us "onCreate: workds", "touch: down", "screen: null", "screen: menu" and "screen: game"

Comment: it seems the code is not full. Could you post the whole activity?

Comment: Even if I remove all my code and only this code above is left it happens!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class is called *Memoration* and implements *InputProcessor*. However, in your *create()* callback, you are creating another instance of *Memoration* and setting that as the input processor, so it's that instance that is getting the callbacks. And, because *create()* isn't being called for that instance, *screen* is never initialized.

Try this instead...

```
@Override
public void create() {
   screen = Screen.MENU;
   Gdx.app.log("onCreate", "works");
   Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rod! Appreciate it but unlucky it's not working now either, same result!

Comment: Odd. Works for me. Here's the code that I used (should work standalone). http://pastebin.com/mAyg2qFY

Comment: Yes it works for me too! (Except for import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;)

I will check it out what I'm doing wrong with my code! 

Thank you for the help.